# What is the difference between the presence or absence of an interface in passing data from fragment to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to pass data to the `activity` when the `dialog fragment`'s window is closed.

I have defined a method in the activity as a way to pass data.

In the fragment, I used `getActivity()` to get a reference to the activity and call the corresponding method.

By the way, I have seen most of the other articles use the `interface`.

Those articles defined the interface in the fragment and implemented it in the activity.

And in the fragment, use `getActivity()` or the `context of onAttach()` to call the implementation method after casting.

Why do you necessarily define an interface?

The same way I do it, the result seems to be the same.

this is my code

***MainActivity.java***

```
public class WriteRoutineActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   
    List<RoutineModel> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_write_routine);

        initViews();
    }

    public void getComments(List<Comment> comments, int pos) {
        Object obj = routineAdapter.getRoutineItem(pos);
        if(obj instanceof RoutineModel) {
            RoutineModel item = (RoutineModel) obj;
            item.setComments(comments);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
```

***WCDialogFragment.java***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements CommentModel.EditInputListener {
    private final List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    int pos;

    public WritingCommentDialogFragment(int pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setWindowSize();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);
        bindViews(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
        super.onCancel(dialog);
        if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof WriteRoutineActivity) {
            WriteRoutineActivity activity = (WriteRoutineActivity) getActivity();
            activity.getComments(comments, pos); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using interfaces is more desirable approach. There are a lot of benefits. Interface gives us an understanding of what capabilities some entity has. In your case extracting this method to interface tells that activity is able to retrieve list of comments. Anyone who will read code base with interface will immediately understand what else API instance of this class is provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might not answer all your questions, but making use of an interface takes away a lot of relevant details, which in this case is actually a good thing, making your code a bit more leniet and reusable. If you pass in an interface, you just have to make sure that the fragment/activity (or whatever) also implements this same interface and then overrides the relevant methods. These methods you're overriding can have their own implementations, but it wouldn't matter.

Looking at your code:

```
@Override
public void onCancel(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);
    if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof WriteRoutineActivity) {
        WriteRoutineActivity activity = (WriteRoutineActivity) getActivity();
        activity.getComments(comments, pos); 
    }
}
```

the problem lies with:

```
if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof WriteRoutineActivity)
```

so now this dialog is tightly coupled to the `WriteRoutineActivity`.

what happens if I wanted to use this dialog in `FooBarActivity`?

```
if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof WriteRoutineActivity || FooBarActivity)
```

and now another class ?

```
if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof WriteRoutineActivity || FooBarActivity ||.....)
```

so you're violating SOLID principles because you will have to change this as your code is being used in different activities - for every new activity you want to use this in, you have to go and change your dialog

Comment: If I use interface, `context intanceof
OnDialogClosedListener` can be solved with just one code.
Without the need for multiple types of casting checks.